# why javascript cannot access external variable with the same name inside the closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

The following piece of javascript code:

```
function init(name) {
  function displayName() {
    var name = name || "default string";
    console.log(name); 
  }
  displayName();
}
init("parameter string"); //here is unexpected ouput: "default string"
```

Why does the above code not output "`parameter string`" as expected?
Thanks in advance.

update:
However, the following code works as expected:

```
function init(name) {
  var name = name||"Mozilla";
  console.log("init name:",name)
}
init("param string")//output: "init name: param string" as expected
```

what's the different between the two codes?

Comment: it should be `name = name ?? "default string";`

Comment: Because you explicitly told it **not** to, by declaring a *new* `name` variable in the inner scope, shadowing the outer `name` parameter. Remove the `var` so you're using the `name` parameter.

Comment: I voted to close as typo/non-repro, but it's probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript), or any question asking what `var` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because On the left side, you declare a variable called `name` which will be `undefined` before get initialization, so the `name` value on the right side will be undefined, so name variable will initialize with "default string".

```js
function init(name) {
  function displayName() {
    var name = name || "default string";
    console.log(name); 
  }
  displayName();
}
init("parameter string"); //here is unexpected ouput: "default string"
```

But if you remove `var` as @T.J. Crowder suggest, you will re-assign the `name` parameter which already has value.

```js
function init(name) {
  function displayName() {
    name = name || "default string";
    console.log(name); 
  }
  displayName();
}
init("parameter string"); //here is unexpected ouput: "default string"
```

If you replace `var` with `let` it will give an error "Cannot access 'name' before initialization", which explain the point.

```js
function init(name) {
  function displayName() {
    let name = name || "default string";
    console.log(name); 
  }
  displayName();
}
init("parameter string"); //here is unexpected ouput: "default string"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you declared same `name` variable inside closure function..

The below code should work

```
function init(name) {
  function displayName() {
    var name1 = name || "default string";
    console.log(name1); 
  }
  displayName();
}
init("parameter string")
```

Otherwise you can directly check without declaring variable again

```
name = name || "default string";
```